# Ao enviar uma notificação, como eu faço para mostrar o ícone do badge?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, push-notification

Esse é o OnCreate da minha MainActivity. Veja que eu setei um badge com valor 10 para testes. Agora preciso fazer, com que ao enviar uma Notificação, eu possa incrementar o ícone do badge com a quantidade de Notificação que está sendo recebida pela minha App. A mensagem é recebida por outra classe(GcmService) e posto os dois métodos que recebem e criam a mensagem.

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            instance = this;
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
            Badge badge = new Badge(this);
            badge.count(10);
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }
```

Aqui estão os dois métodos da classe Gcm que trata a mensagem.

```
protected override void OnMessage(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            Log.Info("PushHandlerBroadcastReceiver", "GCM Message Received!");

            var msg = new StringBuilder();

            if (intent != null && intent.Extras != null)
            {
                foreach (var key in intent.Extras.KeySet())
                    msg.AppendLine(key + "=" + intent.Extras.Get(key).ToString());
            }

            //Store the message
            var prefs = GetSharedPreferences(context.PackageName, FileCreationMode.Private);
            var edit = prefs.Edit();
            edit.PutString("last_msg", msg.ToString());
            edit.Commit();

            string message = intent.Extras.GetString("message");
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
            {
                createNotification("New todo item!", "Todo item: " + message);
                return;
            }

            string msg2 = intent.Extras.GetString("msg");
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(msg2))
            {
                createNotification("New hub message!", msg2);
                return;
            }

            //CrossBadge.Current.SetBadge(++contador, "Novo desconto");
            createNotification("Solicitação de novo desconto", "Novo desconto na fila");//msg.ToString());


        }

        void createNotification(string title, string desc)
        {
            contador++;
            //Create notification
            var notificationManager = GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;

            //Create an intent to show ui
            var uiIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));

            //Use Notification Builder
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

            //Create the notification
            //we use the pending intent, passing our ui intent over which will get called
            //when the notification is tapped.
            var notification = builder.SetContentIntent(PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, uiIntent, 0))
                                      .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.icon)
                                      .SetTicker(title)
                                      .SetContentTitle(title)
                                      .SetContentText(desc)

                    //Set the notification sound
                    .SetSound(RingtoneManager.GetDefaultUri(RingtoneType.Notification))

                    //Auto cancel will remove the notification once the user touches it
                    .SetAutoCancel(true).Build();



            //string count = contador.ToString();
            //CrossBadge.Current.SetBadge(++contador, "Nova solicitação de desconto");

            //Show the notification
            notificationManager.Notify(1, notification);
        }
```

Só preciso fazer com que o Badge que está na MainActivity gere apenas o badge de acordo com a(s) mensagem(ns) recebida e para isso eu preciso setar alguma coisa na MainActivity. Como eu faço isso?

Uso XF

Comment: Ainda GCM? Não atualizou para FCM não o Xamarim?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado, bom dia. Então, estava tentando com FCM mas não estava conseguindo. Então, peguei esse código de um cara e coloquei e consegui enviar PN. Desde esse período, não tentei mais nada com PN, pois o meu está funcionando. O cara me disse, que mesmo FCM utiliza por baixo dos panos o GCM, isso não entendo. Eu tenho outro App para desenvolver e nesse vou testar o FCM sim. Só preciso terminar esse. Quanto ao post, eu criei uma property static no MainActivity e seto ela pela classe GCMService. Se true, gera o badge, assim: `Autorizador.Android.MainActivity.HasMessage = true`.

Comment: Já consegui. Criei uma classe de serviço, em realidade Application e nela eu chamo o badge e quando eu quero resetar, passo count(0) e isso dá certo.